# AngularJS $resource update/ PUT operation?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm confused as to how exactly to update a resource using $save. I've read the angular resource documentation and looked at other posts on stack overflow but I cannot seem to perform an update operation on an existing object.

For example, I have an event object and I want to update its name and location properties. I have the start of a function that correctly takes in the eventId of a singular event.

Here is the function so far:

```
 eventService.updateEvent = function (eventId, eventName, eventLocation) {

   // Defines the resource (WORKS)
   var Event = $resource('/api/events/:id/', {id:'@_id'});

   // Gets the event we're talking about (WORKS)
   var event = Event.get({'id': eventId});

   // TODO update event

  };
```

How do i successfully update this resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

When I defined the resource, I defined the PUT operation as a custom method called 'update'.

I called get on that resource and looked up a particular object by ID. 
Using a promise, I was able to update the resource using the 'update method' if the object was found, else throw an error.

```
eventService.updateEvent = function (eventId,eventName,eventLocation) {

     // Define the event resource, adding an update method
     var Event = $resource('/api/events/:id/', {id:'@_id'},
     { 
         update: 
         {
            method: 'PUT'
         }
    });

    // Use get method to get the specific object by ID
    // If object found, update. Else throw error
    Event.get({'id': eventId}).$promise.then(function(res) {
       // Success (object was found)

       // Set event equal to the response
       var e = res;

       // Pass in the information that needs to be updated
       e.name = eventName;
       e.location = eventLocation;

       // Update the resource using the custom method we created
       Event.update(e)

    }, function(errResponse) {
       // Failure, throw error (object not found)
       alert('event not found');
   });

};
```